# Flexbox Items going outside its container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate a math game for a University project with HTML CSS and JS. During the layout, my flexbox items are going outside their container. I gave them a thick border so it is easier to see what is happening. I'm trying to design it first for mobile as I show in the picture below.

[See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1uuV.png)

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 1em;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}


.flex-item {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(0, 255, 64);
}
```

[Here is the full code in codepen](https://codepen.io/grojas31/pen/WNpWMqr)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Link not existing, kindly update the link or remove the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `gap` in your grid. You need to account for the `0.5em` padding added on both sides of your element. To do this, you can use the CSS `calc` method. Set the `width` of `.answer-options` to `calc(100% - 1em);`, `1em` being what you get when you add the `.5em` and `.5em` on either side of your grid. You're subtracting that `1em` from the `100%` width.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is solved :) 
And I have another doubt about the top element `.equation`  when I try to take 100% of the space of the container with `width: 100%;` it goes completely out of the container.

Comment: Take the `border` properties off the `.flex-item` child element of `.equation` and change `.equation`'s `width` to `calc(100% - 2em - 6px);`, which takes into account both the `padding` and the `border-width`. This is easier if you use CSS variables, by the way.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

in `.container` I changed margin to padding and the problem got resolved.